# Java - convert from byte to int (not ascii value)

Tags: java, int, byte

I got a problem with my java application,
I have a String that I converted into a byte array
but I cannot read the Integers as int values anymore,
so if there is for example a '3' at the 3rd position maybe in "ab3cd",
I cannot just say

```
String s = "ab3cd";
byte[] b = s.getBytes();
int i = b[2];
```

because then it tells me the ascii value of 3 and not 3 as itself.
How can I convert the byte value into an int value?

Thank you for helping! :-)

Comment: You can use `int i = Character.getNumericValue(b[2]);`

Comment: `Character.getNumericValue("ab3cd".charAt(2));`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the simple answer, I was looking for! To both of you! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Subtract `'0'`:

```
int i = b[2] - '0';
```